# Using crypto module in Typescript

Tags: typescript, sha1

in my typescript project I'm trying to get SHA1 Hash with the help of crypto module from nodejs.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

console.log(crypto.createHash('sha1').update('message').digest('hex'));
```

but after running it, the only thing I get is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHash' of undefined
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way to get SHA1 hash in typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the import line to:

```
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
```